# Importing Mobile Push Contacts to new MC Instance

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

We are working to migrate from one Marketing Cloud instance to another one and we have a mobile app connected to Mobile Push.

Is there a way to migrate all the contacts from one instance to the other and be able to message them when you setup the app in the new instance? Or do we need to start from scratch and as users install the new version of the app they will appear as optins in the new instance and then you can send them push notifications from the new instance?

Comment: Its best to have the SDK handle all of this